# erp next installation completed but there is not open in browser

Tags: erpnext

erpnext installation completed but there is not open in browser what reasons help me
please help me what the reasons and create the new site also but not open brower and also check in t different browsers.I enter the this commands
bench new-site erp.aitorch.com
bench use erp.aitorchAit.com

[this is will appear in my window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP7uQ.png)